# Node.js asynchronous programming - copy binary file stream

Tags: node.js

I want to read all bytes in file A, subtract 0x80 from each byte, and write the results to file B.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
try:
    open file A for reading
    open file B for writing

    loop until EOF:
        x = next byte from file A
        x = x - 0x80;
        write x to file B

finally:
   close file A
   close file B
```

How can this be done in node.js using the **asynchronous** file system functions?

I gave it a shot, but gave up when my code got half a dozen levels deep with callbacks and exception handling. Please teach me clean asynchronous programming. :)

Comment: Use the stream interface to the file system to do this cleanly.  See [here](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/what-are-streams) for the basic concept.

Answer (score 0):

*"but gave up when my code got half a dozen levels deep with callbacks and exception handling"...*

that's called "callback hell", and it is inherent to async programming.

### Possible solutions:

You can use **wait.for**, a ***very simple*** lib I've developed recently, to program sequentially (as in your pseudocode) avoiding callback hell.
check:
http://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

You can also google "nodejs promises", https://github.com/kriskowal/q
and "nodejs async lib", https://github.com/caolan/async
but consider that promises and async libs add complexity in order to ease the pain  of callback hell (they also provide a lot of functionality, but, at the expense of adding new concepts and more complexity).

Note: In the specific case of your example, core node 'fs' module- http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html - makes an exception to ***"nothing should block in node"*** and eases callback hell by providing two versions of almost every function, one standard async and another one blocking *Sync.